# How did Professor Lupin already know all the students' names during his first class?

Tags: harry-potter

At Professor Lupin's first Defence Against the Dark Arts class, he let students face a Boggart, and while doing that he calls all the students that faced the Boggart by their name.

How can he know all the student's names from the very beginning of the year?

Comment: That's kinda what *competent teachers* are supposed to know...

Comment: He was given a class list?

Comment: He can't just know that there should be introducing phase. You can have a list of names but you can't just know people by that.

Comment: Lupin knew *Harry's* class.  I wouldn't be surprised if an old friend of James and Lily had made it his business to learn all about students (and their families, like the Malfoys, especially after the previous year's diary plot) who had close contact with Harry.

Comment: @Radhil True but we see other new teachers (Moody and Umbridge, for instance) ask the names of their new students in the first class. So even if learning the names beforehand were an option it wasn't one that everyone took advantage of.

Comment: @user14111 Would teachers have had such documentation in 1993?

Comment: @Radhil Really? That's news to me. I guess all college teachers are incompetent.

Comment: @user14111 Not necessarily. In germany its highly unusual to take pictures of students. So even while there is an electronic roster, it would likely not include pictures.

Comment: Joined this community just to say - when I was teaching intro college math in 07-09 we had rosters with student ID pictures on them.  After that I went on to various different schools where we had rosters without pictures.  I think these days the pictures may be less common but I know firsthand it definitely happens.  Also when I was an undergraduate I know my professors had access to our student ID pics.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Assuming we take the book at face-value, there's really no good indication that he actually knew which student was which, aside from those that he'd already met; Harry, Ron and Hermione. Where the others are concerned, he may simply be calling out names from the register or guessing who they are from their names and appearances.

> ‘Cool, sir!’ said Dean Thomas in amazement. ‘Thank you, Dean,’ said
>   Professor Lupin, putting his wand away again. ‘Shall we proceed?’

Without wanting to seem blunt, it doesn't take a genius to recognise the only black child in the class from their description.

> ‘I was hoping that Neville would assist me with the first stage of the
>   operation,’ he said, ‘and I am sure he will perform it admirably.’
>   Neville’s face went, if possible, even redder. Snape’s lip curled, but
>   he left, shutting the door with a snap.

Lupin may have recognised Neville from his resemblance to his parents or he may simply have called on him to piss Snape off.

> ‘This means,’ said Professor Lupin, choosing to ignore Neville’s small
>   splutter of terror, ‘that we have a huge advantage over the Boggart
>   before we begin. Have you spotted it, Harry?’

He already met Harry and would recognise him from his distinctive scar

> There was a roar of laughter; the Boggart paused, confused, and
>   Professor Lupin shouted, ‘Parvati! Forward!’

Again, a simple matter of deduction and observation

> ‘Seamus!’ roared Professor Lupin. Seamus darted past Parvati.

A name called from the register. Also, the class was talking when he walked in and it's a pretty fair deduction that Seamus would have an Irish accent.

> ‘Excellent! Ron, you next!’ Ron leapt forward.

He'd already met Ron on the train.

> and five each to Hermione and Harry.’

He'd already met Hermione on the train.

Comment: Your explanation looks like what Sherlock Holmes could do when making a demonstration of his analysis skill ! Good job :)

Comment: It's actually a great teaching technique to learn names as well.

Comment: "Without wanting to seem blunt, it doesn't take a genius to recognise the only black child in the class from their description." Where would he have seen a description of Dean stating that he's a black child?

Comment: @Moogle - from his fellow teachers?

Comment: Teachers don't necessarily give a description of every single student to new teachers. It would take too long and be pointless, as you can't accurately describe every student. So unless you think they would go around pointing out the BAME students I think it's a bit of a baseless and far-fetched assumption.

Comment: It could be as simple as calling a name from the roster and looking to see who steps forward.

Comment: ...or perhaps he did a roll-call at the start of the class that the author didn't bother transcribing (because that would be boring).

Comment: @T.E.D. "Lupin looked down at the register, and read out the name in front of him, "Seamus?". A boy, whom Lupin assumed to be Seamus, lest some practical joke was being played on him by the class, responded. He looked down at the register yet again, and read the next name out, "Dean". He knew who this was before anyone responded as the other teachers had made a point to inform him of all the black kids in his class, as is common practice at Hogwarts. Moving onto the next name Lupin called out, "Lisa?"..."

Comment: Prior preparation and planning prevents piss poor performance

Comment: Even muggle schools commonly have class lists (and sometimes seating charts) with photos; I imagine these would be far more effective if magical.

Comment: @Moogle - I strongly suspect that he would have been given a bit of an overview on the class by Dumbledore and/or McGonagall before his first lesson.

Answer (score 1):

Something very simple has been overlooked that was covered in Book 1 but glossed over in the movies. The list includes a requirement for a name tag which is to be worn at all times and there is never any mention of it not being required in later years. If all of the students are wearing the name tag as required then it would be very simple for Lupin or any other professor to know the names of the students by reading the name tag.

Uniform list from the Potter [Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Supply_list)

> Three Sets of Plain Work Robes (Black)
>   One Plain Pointed Hat (Black) for day wear
>   One Pair of Protective Gloves (dragon hide or similar)
>   One Winter Cloak (Black, silver fastenings)
>   Please note that all student's clothes should carry name-tags at all times.

Comment: The name tag is sewn inside the clothes and identifies the owner for shared laundry.  It's not worn outside the clothes!